# Xamarin Form - Taking photo exception

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am getting the following exception when trying to take a photo: "***Unable to get file location. This most likely means that the file provider information is not set in your Android Manifest file. Please check documentation on how to set this up in your project.***"

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="MYPACKAGENAME.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I have a file under Resources/xml called file_paths.xml, it's BuildAction is set to AndroidResource, and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

I am using the Xam.Plugin.Media plugin (from James Montemagno), and when I call TakePhotoAsync, I get the exception

```
await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    Directory = "MyFolder",
    SaveToAlbum = true,
    CompressionQuality = 40,
    CustomPhotoSize = 35,
    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
    MaxWidthHeight = 1000,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the solution but when I've used this library in the past I've used a different provider name. So instead of

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"...
```

I used

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the following error on startup: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar",

Answer (score 0):

I had down a demo which used the code you had provided and the same nuget package. I also met the error. I tried many ways and when I set "android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" it worked well. So you can have a try.

The Android Manifest file:

```
<application android:label="App15.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
    <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get the same error though.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. I build the demo following your question. I had show my Android Manifest file above. You can check out. Was your provider label in the application label?@DarthSerpical

Comment: It seems it's my device that is causing the error, not the simulator. When I run it on the simulator, it works

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall the application on your device?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. It happens while I'm debugging too

Comment: Can this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104762/xamarin-plugin-media-unable-to-get-file-location) help you? May the cause is the simulator doesn't have a real sd card.@DarthSerpical